# Remove dock badge after it is already set

Tags: electron

In electron, I have set the badge to a text of "." and once the window gets focused on again, I want to remove the badge. However, if I set it to empty string or undefined, the badge is still there.

How can I remove the badge from an app's dock icon once it has already been set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it to `null` and the dock badge goes away

Comment: Setting it to undefined or empty string works as well. I was being dumb. Thanks for the help!

Comment: setting up null will throw an error don't use that.Instead set empty string or undefined

Answer (score 1):

In Electron v1.7.6, if you set `null`, this will cause `Could not call remote function` error. So, instead of using `null`, set an empty string `''` like the following:

```js
import electron from 'electron'
const app = electron.app || electron.remote.app

app.dock.setBadge('')
```